# how do i print the names of the items without looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

[image]

This is the code:

```
itemDict = {"Laptop" : 3499.0, "Keyboard" : 10.5, "Harddisk" : 159.3, "Mouse" : 8.9}

print("Item Listing")

print("---------------------")

def displayItem(itemDict):
    i = list(itemDict.values())

    return i
def names(itemDict):
    j = list(itemDict.keys())

    return j
for names in names(itemDict):
    for values in displayItem(itemDict):
        print(names + " - $" + str(values))
```

Comment: Why do you not want to loop?

Comment: If you `print(itemDict)` directly you get rid of the apparent loop, but your program does not get any faster for there is still underlying loop in dict's __str__ implementation. In a line, printing a list is O(n) operation and the need for a loop is intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

Or a one-liner:

```
d = {"Laptop" : 3499.0, "Keyboard" : 10.5, "Harddisk" : 159.3, "Mouse" : 8.9}
print('\n'.join(' - $'.join(map(str,i)) for i in zip(sorted(list(d.keys())*len(d),key=list(d.keys()).index),sorted(list(d.values())*len(d),key=list(d.values()).index))))
```

Comment: mmm, how horrible it looks! :)

Comment: @eyllanesc haha. It does look horrible, but that's the only one-liner i can figure out

Comment: I do not like to answer these types of questions because they do not make sense

Comment: @eyllanesc This is kind of a strange question, but still answerable, and understandable

Comment: In what project in production are you going to use this type of code ?, for me it is closer to encouraging a bad practice. :)

Comment: For me not every question must be answered even if it has an answer, or at least to point out the inconvenience of using that answer, any answer that meets the requirements of the OP is going to be illegible and that is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a bit simpler if that is what you are looking for:

```
for i in itemsDict:
    print i, itemsDict[i]
```

that will print the key:value pair

For a dynamically changing Dict I don't think there is another way to print all the values other than iterating through it.

Hope that helps :)